# Copy cell values between XLSM files with Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf

I have two `XLSM` files and try to copy cell values between files in Java code with `Apache POI`.
First file is initialized as follows:

```
File file = new File(GlobalVariables.XLSM);
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
XSSFWorkbook workbook = XSSFWorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(inputStream);
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(recordcount+4);
Cell cell;
```

Second file:

```
File prevfile = new File(PrevResXLS);
FileInputStream prevInputStream = new FileInputStream(prevfile);
XSSFWorkbook prevworkbook = XSSFWorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(prevInputStream);
XSSFSheet prevsheet = prevworkbook.getSheetAt(0);
XSSFRow prevrow = prevsheet.getRow(0);
Cell prevCell;
```

After that I try to copy cells by predefined condition. Cells should be copied to different column, than in original files, so I use subtraction for this purpose in my code.

```
        for (Row r : prevsheet) {
            if (r.getRowNum()==0) continue;
            if(r.getCell(1).toString().equals(trans_filename)){
                prevCell = prevrow.getCell(21);
                prevCell.setCellValue(r.getCell(21-13).toString());
                prevCell = prevrow.getCell(22);
                prevCell.setCellValue(r.getCell(22-13).toString());
                prevCell = prevrow.getCell(23);
                prevCell.setCellValue(r.getCell(23-13).toString());
                prevCell = prevrow.getCell(24);
                prevCell.setCellValue(r.getCell(24-13).toString());
                prevCell = prevrow.getCell(25);
                prevCell.setCellValue(r.getCell(25-13).toString());
                prevCell = prevrow.getCell(26);
                prevCell.setCellValue(r.getCell(26-13).toString());
                prevCell = prevrow.getCell(27);
                prevCell.setCellValue(r.getCell(27-13).toString());
                prevCell = prevrow.getCell(28);
                prevCell.setCellValue(r.getCell(28-13).toString());
                prevCell = prevrow.getCell(29);
                prevCell.setCellValue(r.getCell(29-13).toString());
                prevCell = prevrow.getCell(30);
                prevCell.setCellValue(r.getCell(30-13).toString());
                prevCell = prevrow.getCell(31);
                prevCell.setCellValue(r.getCell(31-13).toString());
                prevCell = prevrow.getCell(32);
                prevCell.setCellValue(r.getCell(32-13).toString());
                prevCell = prevrow.getCell(33);
                prevCell.setCellValue(r.getCell(33-13).toString());
            }
        }
```

I get `java.lang.NullPointerException`, but file, sheet and cells are exists.

Comment: Which line gives the NPE? And what object does that correspond to?

Comment: @Gagravarr : At this line: `prevCell.setCellValue(r.getCell(27-13).toString());`, it is Cell interface.

Comment: `prevrow.getCell` as well as `r.getCell` may return null. So null check is always necessary.